# R coding: How to take a conditional sum/mean with multiple conditions in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with company quarterly data and would like to take the annual average or sum (based on variable type) across all four quarters given 2 conditions:  year and company.

For instance, Company i in 1984 would have an average inventory value and total revenue, say Companyi_I1984 and Companyi_REV1984 respectively, based on four distinct quarterly values.  I am currently using these lines of code - for the mean and sum - but R keeps returning "NA" and I've searched and searched for alternatives but nothing seems to work:

```
Companyi_I1984 <- with(R, mean(I [FY == "1984" & Co == "AAR CORP" ]))
Companyi_REV1984 <- with(R, sum(REVQ [FY == "1984" & Co == "AAR CORP" ]))
```

R is my dataframe
I <- quarterly inventory
REVQ <- quarterly revenue

I've included example R code below for reference:

```
company<-c("xray", "xray", "xray",  "xray", "xray", "xray", "xray",  "xray", "kilo", "kilo", "kilo", "kilo" )  

year <-c("1984","1984","1984","1984", "1985", "1985","1985", "1985","1984","1984","1984","1984" )

qtr <-c("1","2","3","4", "1", "2","3", "4","1", "2","3","4")

IQ <- rnorm(12,0,10)  
REVQ <- rnorm(12,0,10)  
AssetQ <- rnorm(12,0,10)  
CashQ  <- rnorm(12,0,10)  

#Show dataframe  
data<-data.frame( year, qtr, company, IQ, REVQ, AssetQ, CashQ )
```

In this example, I would want a mean or sum for 'xray_1984', 'xray_1985' and 'kilo_1984'. Notice how the same year can appear across different companies.

This is the second stage to my first question, found here:
[R coding: How to keep records with 4 complete quarters of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38113824/4318393)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you ~ M

Comment: Your previous question has lots of leads pointing you towards where you need to go; you could adapt any of the approaches, e.g. `library(dplyr) ; data %>% group_by(year, company) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum, mean), -qtr)` Use the docs and vignettes.

Comment: dplyr is magic, thank you @alistaire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'year', 'company', we loop through the columns (`.SD`) specified in the `.SDcols`, get the `sum` and `sd`, and `unlist` to get the expected output.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) list(Sum=sum(x), Mean = mean(x))),
         recursive=FALSE), by = .(year, company), .SDcols = IQ:CashQ]
#    year company     IQ.Sum   IQ.Mean   REVQ.Sum  REVQ.Mean AssetQ.Sum AssetQ.Mean  CashQ.Sum CashQ.Mean
#1: 1984    xray 36.2510271 9.0627568 -16.814705 -4.2036762  -1.218832  -0.3047081 -31.500185  -7.875046
#2: 1985    xray  7.2565640 1.8141410 -11.509279 -2.8773198  -4.900577  -1.2251443  -5.229553  -1.307388
#3: 1984    kilo  0.6851807 0.1712952  -2.022284 -0.5055711  14.593264   3.6483161 -22.693697  -5.673424
```